# how to write .tiff file to disk

Tags: javascript, node.js

i have an endpoint the when is called it returns back a `.tiff`file. as shown in the code below, i am writing the `.tiff` file to the disk using `writeFile`. despite the file is created and saved properly and contains data "its size is not zero", but stil i cant
read it via `readFile`

is there any specifications or parameters i should consider when writing `.tiff` file to disk

**code**:

```
response.on('close', ()=>{

    writeToFile("test-4",data,'tiff')
    .then((msg)=>{
        console.log(msg)
        readFile("test-4.tiff")
        .then((data)=>{
            fromArrayBuffer(data.buffer)
            .then((geoTIFF)=>{
                geoTIFF.getImage()
                .then((img)=> {
                    console.log(img.fileDirectory.GDAL_METADATA);
                    console.log(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), img.getSamplesPerPixel());
                })
                .catch((e)=>console.log("img.errorMessage:",e))
            })
            .catch((e)=> console.log("geoTIFF.errorMessage:",e))
        })
        .catch((e)=> console.log("data.errorMessage:",e))
    })
    .catch((e)=>{
        console.log(msg)
    })  
});
```

**writeToFile**:

```
export function writeToFile(path,contents,ext='.tiff') {
    let newExt = ''
    return new Promise((resolve,reject)=> {
        if (typeof (path) !== "string") {
            reject(new Error("path is not a string.Did you pass string-object using new String(..)"))
        }
        if (typeof (ext) !== "string") {
            reject(new Error("extension is not a string.Did you pass string-object using new String(..)"))
        }

        if (contents == undefined) {
            reject(new Error("contents to be written to the file is undefined"))
        }

        if (ext.charAt(0) === '.') {
            newExt = ext
        } else {
            newExt = '.' + ext
        }
        
        fs.writeFile(path+newExt, content,(error)=> {
            if (error) {
                reject(new Error("error occured while writing data to file.error:",error," file:",path+newExt))
                throw error
            }
            resolve("successfully saved the data to file:",path+newExt)
        });
    })
}
```

**readFile**:

```
export function readFile(path) {
    return new Promise((resolve,reject) => {
        if (typeof (path) !== "string") {
            console.log("path:",typeof (path));
            reject(new Error("path is not a string.Did you pass string-object using new String(..)"))
        }

        resolve (fs.readFileSync(path))
    })
}
```

Comment: Your `writeToFile` function does not return a promise. If should even throw an error "resolve is not defined". Are you sure you sent the correct code ?

Comment: @Seblor i updated the code -..pls have a look

Comment: `fs.writeFile(path+newExt, buf,` your data is in the parameter named `contents`  not `buf`

Comment: @PatrickEvans adapted it

Comment: Are you using `fs.readFile` ? Because it does not return a promise, it uses a callback. Also can you explain what you mean with "i cant read it" ? Does it throw an error ?

Comment: @Seblor i posted readFile..pls have a look

Comment: can you explain what you mean with "i cant read it" ? Does it throw an error ?

Comment: @Seblor it does not throw an error.though, it is created with the designated extention which is .tiff. but when i double clikc it ii receive a window with the following message:the data can not be read.this is not a valie Bitamp data or the file format is not supported

Comment: Okay, so the file does not have the proper content that is expected for the TIFF file. Have your tried opening the file with notepad ? Maybe you have an unexpected string like |Object object] or the like. What is the content of the `data` variable ?

Comment: @Seblor i did open it with text editor..it contains data and it seems valid

Comment: Can you add a link to download the file in your question ?

Comment: @Seblor i am afraid i cant..but for the same url, i consumed it using another project written in angular and python, and it downloaded the tiff correctly and i can open it and see the content of the tiff. but the same url iin nodejs sample project causes the issue explained in this question

Comment: Then compare the contents of the 2 files and update your question with the new details.